# Enable mail box from C# powershell

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, iis, exchange-server

The code to enable mail box for an on prem exchange server works when run in debug mode from Visual studio but fails when deployed on IIS on the same instance.The commands also work from Powershell Console
It throws exception cannot connect to server access denied.

Could some one pls help me with this?

PFB the snippet that works perfectly fine when run from Visual studio debug mode and fails when run from code deployed on IIS

```
 string connectionUri = strConURI;
  string loginPassword = Pwd;
           SecureString secpassword = new SecureString();
           foreach (char c in loginPassword)
           {
               secpassword.AppendChar(c);
           }
           PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(Usercred, secpassword);

            Runspace runspace = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();

           PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
            command.AddCommand("New-PSSession");
            command.AddParameter("ConfigurationName", "Microsoft.Exchange");
            command.AddParameter("ConnectionUri", new Uri(connectionUri));
            command.AddParameter("Credential", credential);
            command.AddParameter("Authentication", "Basic");
        //    command.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned");
            powershell.Commands = command;


            runspace.Open();
            powershell.Runspace = runspace;
            Collection<System.Management.Automation.PSObject> 
                result = powershell.Invoke();

            if (powershell.Streams.Error.Count > 0 || result.Count != 1)
            {

                throw new Exception("failed");
            }


                powershell = PowerShell.Create();
                command = new PSCommand();
                command.AddCommand("Invoke-Command");

                const String ScriptBlock = "Get-User {0} | Enable-RemoteMailbox -RemoteRoutingAddress {1};";
               String ScriptBlockstr = string.Format(ScriptBlock, GetUser, MailboxUser);

               command.AddParameter("ScriptBlock", System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create(ScriptBlockstr));
                command.AddParameter("Session", result[0]);

               powershell.Commands = command;
                powershell.Runspace = runspace;
                var mailBoxes = powershell.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 1):

As we do not know how the MS Exchange server is configured and how your application is triggered its not that easy to troubleshoot that.

At first keep noted that depending on your configuration you could use the ports 5985 (http WinRM), 5986 (https WinRM) or also 443 or 80 (as explained by Microsoft [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wmi/2009/07/22/new-default-ports-for-ws-management-and-powershell-remoting/)) or any port you might have configured. When you use New-PsSession with the ComputerName 5985/5986 is used. If you the ConnectionURI then port 80 or 443 is used (see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wmi/2009/07/22/new-default-ports-for-ws-management-and-powershell-remoting/) for more infos).

With that in your mind here are now some basic troubleshooting steps to check:

1. Check if you are using https or http as ConnectionUri and if there is a difference between them and if one is working as expected
2. The best way is to use https (via ComputerName or ConnectionURI) to eliminate any "security implementations" issues where https is forced and then breaks if you try to bypass https. To configure https for winRM (via 5986) use (check [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2019527/how-to-configure-winrm-for-https) for more details):

`winrm quickconfig -transport:https`

Because if using WinRM and if HTTPS is not the transport, then the target remote computer must be configured in the list of trusted host computers (see below and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384295(v=vs.85).aspx) for more infos).

3. If you use https (either via ComputerName or ConnectionURI) make sure that the server where your solution is running on is trusting the connection. If you are using the ConnectionURI, Enter the URL in the browser on the non Exchange server and check for any SSL certificate issue. Make sure that you use the full qualified domain name here.
4. If you configured on the non Exchange Server a proxy make sure that your connection is bypassing the proxy (see [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/windows/211-set-proxy-on-windows-2012-2012-r2.html)) to avoid that the connection is tried to be done via proxy which isn´t the way you would like to have.
5. Check with telnet if the port from the affected server towards your MS Exchange Server is open (See the port information at the top from that posting)
6. Depending on your configuration you might need to use different Authentications (e.g. Negotiate, Basic, Kerberos, ...). Make sure that you use the correct authentication here for your situation. Keep noted that Kerberos only works in a domain context, that means the non Exchange server must be added to the same ActiveDirectory domain! To test the connection you can use powershell (via run as different user) and you might also bypass some SSL validation checks (SkipCACheck, SkipCNCheck, SkipRevocationCheck) during this connection check. See below for some examples (more info's [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335083(v=exchg.160).aspx)) also check http and https options:

`$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://<FQDN of Exchange Mailbox server>/PowerShell/ -Authentication Negotiate -Credential $UserCredential -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck
Import-PSSession $Session`

Or if you know which authentication should be used use:

`$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://<FQDN of Exchange Mailbox server>/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck
Import-PSSession $Session`

or

`$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://<FQDN of Exchange Mailbox server>/PowerShell/ -Authentication Basic -Credential $UserCredential -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck
Import-PSSession $Session`

7. Is remote powershell enabled for the taskuser you are using?

`Set-User YourTaskUser -RemotePowerShellEnabled $True`

8. Make sure that the MS Exchange powershell directory is configured as required for you and that (for example the expected authentication methods are configured). Start with:

`Get-PowerShellVirtualDirectory "Exchange2010\PowerShell (Default Web Site)"`

9. In most cases, you will be able to work with remote computers in other domains. However, if the remote computer is not in a trusted domain, the remote computer might not be able to authenticate your credentials. To enable authentication, you need to add the remote computer to the list of trusted hosts for the local computer in WinRM (see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700227.aspx)). To do so, type:

   `winrm s winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="RemoteComputer"}'`
10. check if the authentication (= Basic) was changed or if AllowUnencrypted was set to true. Both isn´t a default setup and if done might cause unexpected issues (beside the fact that it limits the security).
11. You can also use [Test-WSMan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.wsman.management/test-wsman?view=powershell-5.1) to check if basic and/or kerberos authentication is working as expected (via http or https and the WinRM port you configured/use). Here are some examples:

`Test-WSMan -ComputerName https://server2008:5986 -Auth basic -Cred B\MY_USER_NAME`

and/or

`Test-WSMan -ComputerName https://server2008:5986 -Auth kerberos`

12. When you are using WinRM make sure that your taskuser is added to the local OS WinRMRemoteWMIUsers group, because per default WinRM is restricted to users in that group or users in the local administration group (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384295(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Comment: We are able to run the commands from powershell console as well as from Visual Studio in debug mode...When the same code is deployed on same server on IIS it throws access denied.

Comment: Did you checked the options above? You didn´t specify if you use https or http in your code, so I totally stumble in the dark here with so less infos you give me... You only repeat your code without checking any if my answers...

Comment: FYI , I did check your answer, and it was a reply to u indicating that it is working in powershell console for the question you had asked. and the authn is Basic which is what is set when running from powershell console , from VS and from IIS. the connection uri is http and not https